# how to compare captcha session value in jquery?

Tags: jquery, session

i have a form which does validation on client side by jquery,i want to compare the value of session for captcha  with the value of the input.but i dont know

1. how to get the session value of captcha and
2. how to compare the session value and the input?

this is how i compare the session but it makes no differnt,for both wrong and right value,it says its wrong.i get the session value via this code:

```
 $('#captchaimg').val()
```

but off course its wrong!

```
if(!($('#6_letters_code').val() == $('#captchaimg').val())){
alert('error');
$('#6_letters_code').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html(" error");
err++;
 }
```

and this is my captcha code:

```
<img src="captcha_code_file.php?rand=<?php echo rand(); ?>" id="captchaimg" />
```

and my input box:

```
<input id="6_letters_code" name="6_letters_code" type="text"  class="form-input"/>
```

Comment: You should only compare the captcha value on the server - that's the point, that it's not possible to retrieve it on the client in any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

img tags don't have values. That's why your code is not working. You probably need to send the image "value" to jquery from your php script.
If php echoes the image "value" into img url(as your example does), there's possibility to get that value.

Edit:

```
if(!(sessionData == $('#captchaimg').val())){
  alert('error');
  $('#6_letters_code').parent().parent().find('.form-error').html(" error");
  err++;
}
```

Comment: thank you.so id                                                     var sessionData = '<?php echo $session['6_letters_code']; ?>';        now how to compare?

Answer (score 1):

1. To get session variable in script file

Get your session value in Viewbag like-

```
   @ViewBag.captchaimg = Session["captchaimg"];
```

place this on the bottom of your view

```
<script>
    var CAPTCHAIMG_URL = "@ViewBag.captchaimg";
</script>
```

Now you can grap this value in your script file

2  In you script file

```
var myval= $("input[id=test]").val();
if (myval == CAPTCHAIMG_URL )
    alert("match");
```

here test is the id of your input. If it help mark it of others :)